# Ajax json timeout / needs to be more efficient

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, lag

I am creating an interactive map. I Won't go into the specifics. But the idea is that a user clicks on a year (stored in var currentyear) and then clicks on a country (name stored in var thenameonly) and then the following ajax runs using both vars:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url, // JQuery loads content.json
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 100000,

    success: (function(data) {
        alert('success');
        $.each(data[thenameonly], function() {
            $.each(this[currentyear], function() {
                if(this.pol_type == 'images/gov_icon.svg'){
                    govcount++;
                } else if(icon == 'images/stock_x_icon.svg'){
                    stockcount++;
                } 
            });
        });
    }),//SUCCESS

    complete: (function(){
        alert('complete');
        $(".gov_numb").html(govcount);
        $(".stock_numb").html(stockcount);
    }),//COMPLETE

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }//ERROR

});
```

It works for a while but as the user continues to click (sometimes on the same country within the same year, running the same query) eventually the success function lags, sometimes for around 5 seconds before running.

It was timing out but I've increased that because the complete function was running before success which was causing other issues.

Here's the json file for reference

```
{
"argentina": [
            {
                "2004": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],


                "2006": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],

                "2008": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ]
            }
],


"australia": [
            {
                "1998": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],                
                "2001": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],
                "2004": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/stock_x_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],
                "2006": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    },
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],

                "2007": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],

                "2010": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    },
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    },
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/stock_x_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],

                "2011": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],

                "2013": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/gov_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ],

                "2014": [
                    {
                        "pol_type":"images/stock_x_icon.svg",
                        "policy":"pol info"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have many more countries and policies etc to add so I'm worried that my structure is going to cause it to break complete.

Any help would be appreciated!

Carl

Comment: `timeout: 100000` is probably the cause of your problems. And you might want to reconsider your `async: false`.

Comment: Hi @Andy, thanks for the reply but as said I only set timeout to 100000 because, well, it was timing out and I'm trying to identify why it's doing that.

Adding async:false is something else I've tried to fix the issue.

After I've ran the ajax (clicked a country) around 25-30 times then success starts lagging, takes around 5-10 seconds to fire the alert('success').

Comment: is `url` changing between calls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the repeated calls of AJAX sending, so add to your code a flag `loading`. You can add it to the global scope, or close in a some function definition:

```
if(!loading){
 loading = true;
 $.ajax({
 async: false,
 url: url, // JQuery loads content.json
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: 'json',
 timeout: 100000,

 success: (function(data) {
    alert('success');
    $.each(data[thenameonly], function() {
        $.each(this[currentyear], function() {
            if(this.pol_type == 'images/gov_icon.svg'){
                govcount++;
            } else if(icon == 'images/stock_x_icon.svg'){
                stockcount++;
            } 
        });
    });
    loading = false;
 }),//SUCCESS

 complete: (function(){
    alert('complete');
    $(".gov_numb").html(govcount);
    $(".stock_numb").html(stockcount);
    loading = false;
 }),//COMPLETE

 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    loading = false;
 }//ERROR

 });
}
```